# Sqoop2 can't find AuditLoggerManager

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I followed the "instructions" [here](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Installation.html) (docs not very good!). Basically, I set a bunch of paths in `sqoop.properties` and `catalina.properties`.

But on `sqoop.sh server start`, the log says it can't find the file audit logger class. I copied a bunch of jar files around but still no luck!

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apach
e.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure in server initialization
        at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:57)
        at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextInitialized(ServerInitializer.j
ava:36)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.ja
va:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: AUDIT_0001:The system was unable to find
 or load audit logger class - Logger Class: org.apache.sqoop.audit.FileAuditLogger
        at org.apache.sqoop.audit.AuditLoggerManager.initializeLoggers(AuditLoggerManager.j
ava:111)
        at org.apache.sqoop.audit.AuditLoggerManager.initialize(AuditLoggerManager.java:80)
        at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:49)
        ... 25 more

Jul 28, 2014 7:11:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.apache.
sqoop.server.ServerInitializer
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.sqoop.framework.JobManager.destroy(JobManager.java:176)
        at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.destroy(SqoopServer.java:36)
        at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextDestroyed(ServerInitiali
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not specified that, but assuming you use hadoop2, you need to add the following jars locations to the common.loader property

- /usr/lib/hadoop/*.jar
- /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*.jar
- /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*.jar
- /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*.jar
- /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*.jar

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/../lib/*.jar,/usr/lib/hadoop/*.jar,/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*.jar,/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*.jar,/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*.jar,/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*.jar
```